# how to recoder my line chart and highlght the date

Tags: r, ggplot2

The question is asking to generate a small multiples of p1 by regions ordered by their confirmed cases on 2020-05-31 from high to low, and highlight each region with colour = "firebrick" and size = 0.8 for each panel.

The data is

[image]

The correct graph should look like

[image]

My code shows a picture with the wrong order and the grey line disappeared, could someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
p2 <- covid19_bg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = confirmed, y = new_cases,group = country_region_bg))+
  geom_line(colour = "gray80", size = 0.4) +scale_y_log10(labels = label_number_si()) scale_x_log10(labels = label_number_si()) +
  geom_line(aes(color=date("2020-05-31")),colour = "firebrick", size = 0.8) +
  facet_wrap(vars(fct_reorder(country_region_bg, confirmed)))
p2
```

Answer (score 0):

You grouped your plot by country_region_bg when you included it in your ggplot aes(). To fix this, remove it from your ggplot aes() and include it in your geom_line aes() instead.